# make servo motor to increase/decrease degree

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, servo

I'm trying to make servo motor to increase or decrease degrees according to user choice.

I've created an code that get input from the user via Serial and according to the input the motor increase or decrease.

But for some reason, when I call each of one of the function the motor start working without a break.
do I miss something over here?

```
 #include <Servo.h>

Servo servo1;  
int currentAngle = 0;
String readString;
void setup()
{
   servo1.attach(8);
   Serial.begin(9600); 
}
void increaseServo(){
  Serial.println('+');
  currentAngle += 5;
  servo1.write(currentAngle);
  delay(15);
}
void decreaseServo(){
  Serial.println('-');
  currentAngle -= 5;
  servo1.write(currentAngle);
  delay(15);
}
void loop() 
{ 
  while(Serial.available()>0) //Allocating the data from Serial Monitor.
  { 
    delay(3);  
    char c = Serial.read();
    readString += c;    
  }
  readString.trim();
  if (readString.length() > 0) {
    if(readString == "+"){ //increase
      increaseServo();
    }else if(readString == "-"){ //decrease
      decreaseServo();
    }
    readString="";
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "But for some reason, when I call each of one of the function the motor start working without a break" - I don't quite understand, what exactly that means. Do you mean, that the motor will continuously move, as soon, as you send either + or - from the Serial Monitor?

Comment: Yes, Exactly the servo continue to move without stop

Comment: Which servo are you using? Common RC servos cannot run without stop, because they have a range of just about -90° to +90°.

Comment: @the_busy bee I am using FT90R